# Fixnum array memory consumption in Ruby 1.9.3 - are arrays getting compressed?

Tags: ruby, arrays, garbage-collection, ruby-1.9.3

I created new arrays and tracked the amount of memory allocated using "Use Size" returned by `GC::Profiler.report`.

Fixnum (size: memory used in bytes):

```
100,000: 900
1,000,000: 1320
10,000,000: 17,552,240
```

Bignum (size: memory used in bytes):

```
100,000: 5081,680
1,000,000: 39,999,520
```

The memory consumption for Bignum makes sense, however the consumption for Fixnum is very weird. I would expect the array to take up at least 4 bytes per elements (more likely 8 bytes because I'm using a 64bit machine). The only logical explanation I can come up with for the low memory consumption is that Fixnum arrays are getting compressed as a bitmap, however I couldn't find any documentation that would support that.

What's going on?

The code used is:

```
GC::Profiler.enable
GC.start
GC::Profiler.report
a = []
1_000_000.times do 
  a << rand(2**62)
end
GC::Profiler.report
```

Results:

```
Index    Invoke Time(sec)       Use Size(byte)     Total Size(byte)         Total Object                    GC Time(ms)
    1              13.541             15700560             19223000               480575        68.00500000000120337518
    2              14.017             15701880             19239360               480984        48.00299999999957378805
```

Comment: Please, add your code used to generate these numbers. You're doing something very strange here. Arrays are not generally compressed as a bitmap, but empty arrays are a special case and might behave in a fashion similar to that. Remember there's no such things as a "Fixnum Array" in Ruby. Arrays are Arrays are Arrays.

Comment: @tadman: Added code. I know this is strange - that's why I'm so confused. It's possible that the GC is reporting stas in a weird way, but it seemed to give logical numbers for Bignums as well as other types I tried.